# (Geometrically) Where are the critical points of the solutions of $y' = x − 2y$? How many critical points can a single solution have?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

**Question Continued:** For what values of $y_{0}$ does the solution $y$ with $y(0) = y_{0}$ have a critical point? When there is one, is it a minimum or a maximum?

This is a question on an MIT OpenCourseWare Practice Problem Sheet for Differential Equations. I am having just a minor doubt in the solution given on the website. I will paste the entire solution here and then state my doubt.

**Solution:** All critical points lie on the $y' = 0-isocline$, which is the line $y = \frac{1}{2}x$. We will argue that solutions above the linear integral curve $y = \frac{1}{2}x − \frac{1}{4}$ have exactly one critical point and solutions below it have no critical points. For graphical intuition, refer to the following screenshot.

[image: Several isoclines and solutions for the equation $y' = x − 2y$]

The question can be rephrased as how do solutions touch or intersect the nullcline. From the graph, it seems that the solution space is divided in two, and the only solutions to intersect the nullcline are those that lie above the $\frac{1}{2}-isocline,$ $y = \frac{1}{2}x − \frac{1}{4}$. The $\frac{1}{2}-isocline$ is an asymptote as can be seen from the figure, and solutions stay above this line for all x if they are above it at any point – for example, if they have a larger $y$-intercept $(y_{0} > -\frac{1}{4})$.

We will show that solutions have a critical point exactly when they are contained in the upper solution space. One direction of this is easy. All the critical points lie on the nullcline, which is in the upper solution space, so a solution has a critical point only if it also lies in the upper solution space. To show the other direction, use the geometry of the isoclines that we found -
 that these are parallel lines of slope $\frac{1}{2}$, of steadily increasing value equal to negative double their $y$-intercept. So solutions in the upper solution space have translational symmetry and all look like the solution through $(0, 0)$, shifted along the nullcline. In particular, they all intersect the nullcline eventually.

Finally, since the nullcline is also a line of slope $\frac{1}{2}$, any solution going through a point on it must pass from the region to the left of it to the region to the right of it, since at the point of intersection $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 < \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, all solutions which intersect the nullcline at all will pass through it exactly once, so they have exactly one critical point.
To summarize, solutions can have either zero or one critical point, and a solution has a critical point if and only if it lies above the linear integral curve $y = \frac{1}{2}x − \frac{1}{4}$ (has $y$-intercept $y_{0} > -\frac{1}{4}$). The picture also makes it appear that all of the critical points are minima.

**Solution End.**

**Doubt:** The problem I am facing is understanding this part of the solution ..."*To show the other direction, use the geometry of the isoclines that we found - that these are parallel lines of slope $\frac{1}{2}$, of steadily increasing value equal to negative double their $y$-intercept.*"...

What does this line mean? I cannot understand what message they want to convey.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of your differential equation is
$$y=\lambda e^{-2x}+\frac x 2-\frac 1 4$$

the solution has a critical point $x_0$ if
$$y'(x_0)=-2\lambda e^{-2x_0}+\frac 12=0$$
which gives $$x_0=\ln (4\lambda) $$ 
for $\lambda=y_0+\frac 1 4>0$.
the condition is then

> $$y_0>-\frac 14$$

Comment: That may be true but I am not interested in the Analytic solution of the differential equation. I am interested in what the geometric solution is and how it behaves. Thank you for your response anyway.

Comment: I appreciate your response but I think you haven't read the entire description.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi It is too long.

Comment: At least read the end part. The bold doubt part.

Comment: They are asymptotes for solutions at $+\infty $.$e^{-2x} $ goes to zero.